# Best learning of gyroscopic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, gyroscopes

I crave to learn the nitty-gritty of attitude dynamics - namely I want to get really up close and personal with angular momentum, gyroscopic motion, non-inertial effects. I'm looking for a resource which teaches me straight-forward yet *rigorous* methods for analyzing spinning motion dynamics - as my question states, gyroscopic motion is an example.

So far I read Kleppner's *An introduction to Mechanics* part on gyroscopic motion. I don't like how methods are outlined for *specific* examples - I want a resource that outlines general equations and uses them to work out solutions to specific examples.

Equally important is a book that is not *condescending*. What I mean is I don't want to read an author who skips parts of demonstrations or refers me to this and that. I want someone who talks to me with a level head and walks me through each step (the best example of such an author is Donald Kirk from *Optimal Control Theory: An Introduction*).

Do you know of such books or YouTube, etc. video series? Thanks a lot!

Comment: N.b.: While it may, at times, be phrased condescendingly, it is not in and of itself condescending to leave out "basic" parts of arguments, or to refer to other sources for a more in-depth, basic, alternative or advanced treatment.

Comment: Yeah I phrased badly. I meant when the author says something like "obviously" or "naturally it follows"- sometimes it's appropriate to say that, but when it isn't I get upset that the person fails to see how to someone learning the subject a complicated conclusion may not appear "obvious".

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/2451

Comment: What does _rigorous_ mean in this context?

Comment: @Qmechanic *Rigorous* means using general equations, vector formulae, etc. - i.e. using the cross product instead of starting to multiply scalars which represent "perpendicular" projections, etc. Basically using a general mathematical approach while taking care to explain what the math "means" - it's a tough mix, but it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: It sounds like _rigorous_ formalism in this context mean _covariant_ formalism. Please note that Phys.SE only allows a limited number of res. recom. questions. The purpose of Phys.SE is mainly to answer actual specific physics questions rather than provide res. recom.